# Under what circumstance Key is not needed when changing StatefulWidget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm confused about the Key mechanism in Flutter. I know how it works. However normally when you change something about a StatefulWidget, say swapping two widgets, in what kind of situation you don't want to change their State accordingly?

P.S. I know how Key works. Just want to know why it is designed this way. Precisely I know it is designed in this way so sometimes you can avoid some overheads. However I can't imagine the scenario when you can benefit from this mechanism.

Comment: I think in simple apps where there are fewer Widgets( or only few are getting rebuilt) `keys` would be completely optional. [Medium Article](https://medium.com/flutter/keys-what-are-they-good-for-13cb51742e7d)

Comment: This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc) it's all about keys and it's from the Flutter Team. Take a look.

Comment: @JRamos29 Thank you. My question came out right after I watched that video. I can't see any reason why I want the State to stay unchanged after I make some changes on the StatefulWidget.

Comment: Well, i could give by example the performance of your app. If you have 10 widgets of the same type in a screen and only one of them must reflect the changes, using keys you can rebuild just that one that must change (This is a simple example. But complex apps can have much more widgets in a single screen). Then you can spare processing and memory, and hence save battery from the device. And nobody likes to use an app that drains out the battery from its device.

Comment: I understand your point, but my question is like this: say there're ten ListTiles, we changed three of them. Of course we would want those three to be refreshed to reflect the changes, and let the rest 7 remain still. My questions is why Flutter is not designed to do it automatically? Flutter gives us the chance to play with Keys manually, so there must be some cases when we want the 3 changed ListTiles to remain still. I can't think of a scenario of it.